# Is it possible to change the endpoints marker in NumberLinePlot in the given code?

Tags: plotting, numerics, plot-themes

I use this code

```
list :=  {Interval[{ 1 , 1.5  }], Interval[{ 3.9 , 5.1 }], Interval[{ 5.7 ,6.7 }], Interval[{ 7.5 , 9.8 }] } ;

NumberLinePlot[list, Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]]
```

and I get this plot

[image]

**Question:**

> Is it possible to change the endpoints marker from "solid points" to "small vertical line"? something like this picture

[image]

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: `NumberLinePlot[list, Spacings -> Prepend[0.2]@ConstantArray[.0, Length@list], PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]] /. Point[{x_, y_}] :> Line[{{x, y - 0.03}, {x, y + 0.03}}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
verticalLine[voffset_: 3] := Line[Table[Offset[{0, voffset i}, #], {i, {-1, 1}}]] &

displayF[voffset_: 3] := ReplaceAll[wp : {White, ___, _Point} :> 
      (wp /. Point -> verticalLine[voffset/4]), 
    Point -> verticalLine[voffset]}];
```

***Examples:***

```
list := {Interval[{1, 1.5}], Interval[{3.9, 5.1}], 
   Interval[{5.7, 6.7}], Interval[{7.5, 9.8}]};

NumberLinePlot[list, 
 Spacings -> Prepend[0.2] @ ConstantArray[.0, Length @ list], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]], 
 DisplayFunction -> displayF[]]
```

[image]

An example with half-open intervals:

```
nlp = NumberLinePlot[{Sin[x] < Cos[x], Sin[x] > Cos[x], 1 < x <= 3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], AbsolutePointSize[10]], 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Show[nlp, DisplayFunction -> displayF[7]]
```

[image]